# Find indexes of multiple max values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an example array:

`var arr = [10, 67, 100, 100];`

I want to find the indexes of the maximum values in the array.

This function finds only one index:

```
function max(arr) {
      var max = arr[0];
      var maxIndex = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i] > max) {
              maxIndex = i;
              max = arr[i];
          }
      }
      return maxIndex;
 }
```

How can  I modify it to return an array of max indexes? In the example array above, it should return

`[2, 3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of just one index, you'll need to keep track of all indices. Give this a try:

```
function max(arr) {
    var max = -Infinity;
    var maxIndices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === max) {
          maxIndices.push(i);
        } else if (arr[i] > max) {
            maxIndices = [i];
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxIndices;
 }
```

Comment: `arr` could be empty. I would initialize `max = -Infinity; maxIndices = []; i = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this;

```js
var arr = [10, 67, 100, 100],
      m = Math.max(...arr),
  maxes = arr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c ==  m ? p.concat(i) : p,[]);
console.log(maxes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function max(arr) {
    var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);

    var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(largest, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }
    return indexes;
}

var arr = [10, 67, 100, 100];
console.log(max(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

JS's [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can help with this task.

```js
// Finds maximum value across entire array
var maxArrSingle = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(
    function(acc,val){
      return Math.max(acc,val);
    },
    -Infinity);
}

// Find indices where array is at max
var maxArrIndexes = function(arr) {
  var max = maxArrSingle(arr);
  return arr.reduce(function(acc,val,idx) {
    if (val >= max) acc.push(idx);
    return acc;
  },[]);
}

// demos
var arr = [10, 67, 100, 100];
console.log(maxArrIndexes(arr));

var arr = [-10, -67, -100, -100, -4000, -9, -90, -90 ];
console.log(maxArrIndexes(arr));

var arr = [];
console.log(maxArrIndexes(arr));

var arr = [0];
console.log(maxArrIndexes(arr));

var arr = [0,0];
console.log(maxArrIndexes(arr));
```

Comment: Returns `[]` for input `[0]` or `[0, 0]` etc. Replace `arr[0] || Number.MIN_VALUE` with e.g. `-Infinity` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this runtime comparison](https://jsfiddle.net/jv1z29jm/2/), I propose searching for the max indices via optimized for-loop:

```js
function max(arr) {
  var max = -Infinity, indices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] < max) continue;
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      indices = [];
      max = arr[i];
    }
    indices.push(i);
  }
  return indices;
}

console.log(max([10, 67, 100, 100])); // [2, 3]
```

Comparing against `arr[i] < max` first is useful since it evaluates to true most of the time and thus enables us to skip to the next iteration with only 1 array access + comparison on average.

**Runtime comparison of the different proposed algorithms:**

According to https://jsfiddle.net/jv1z29jm/2/ - please feel free to update.

- Chrome (48):

  ```
  max_indexOf x 15,381 ops/sec ±2.94% (87 runs sampled)
  max_reduce x 2,909 ops/sec ±2.63% (86 runs sampled)
  max_forloop x 119,964 ops/sec ±1.80% (87 runs sampled)
  max_forloopOptimized x 165,581 ops/sec ±1.50% (87 runs sampled)
  Fastest is max_forloopOptimized
  ```
- Firefox (46):

  ```
  max_indexOf x 56,456 ops/sec ±0.74% (67 runs sampled)
  max_reduce x 74,959 ops/sec ±0.86% (65 runs sampled)
  max_forloop x 73,223 ops/sec ±24.75% (58 runs sampled)
  max_forloopOptimized x 84,567 ops/sec ±9.99% (61 runs sampled)
  Fastest is max_forloopOptimized
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is solution when you find max value at fist and then indexes of all max values.

```js
function multipleMax(arr){
 
 var maxvalue = Math.max(...arr);
 var maxIndexes = [];
 
 for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if(arr[i] == maxvalue){
    maxIndexes.push(i);};
        };
 return maxIndexes;
};

var arr = [10, 67, 100, 100];
console.log(multipleMax(arr));
```