# How to get the 2 max numbers of numbers array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, max

I'm trying to find the index and value of the 2 max numbers from the next array:

{24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20}

I can't use sort method because I need to perserve the index of the items.

In this example, the result should be.

```
max1 = 80
max2 = 64
indexMax1 = 5
indexMax2 = 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780112/find-indexes-of-multiple-max-values-in-array

Comment: That is not exact the same, he is finding about the max index values. I want the index and the value of the max value and the second max value it's similar but have in the algorithm.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exactly the same. It demonstrates a technique that can be easily adapted to meet your requirements with very little effort on your part. Answers that are duplicates don't have to be *exact* - we can't possibly provide answers to every single situation that might come up through time. The answer to *How to add two integer variables named `y` and `z` in C* is the same as the answer to *How to add two integer variables named `a` and `b` in C* - it's not a new question because the variable names don't match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find indexes of multiple max values in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780112/find-indexes-of-multiple-max-values-in-array)

Comment: @KenWhite Yeah, you are right, my intention is not to fill the forum with very similar questions, but i really think that is not easy to adapt the solution of the thread to my problem. Sorry I can't see the solution using this way.

Comment: When you save the max index, you also save the value.. Done.  It works the other way, too - if you're looking for the max values, and want to know the index as well, you store the max value and also the index. I find it easy when you're starting out to just grab a pencil and paper and work through the logic; when you figure it out there, then you convert it to code because you know what you need to do.

Comment: @KenWhite but i'm not looking for the all max occurences, i'm looking for the max and the second max. That is not the same.

Comment: Yes, it is. You're looking for the two max values, so you keep two variables instead o of one. Same problem, same solution. No difference. Paper and pencil and step through it - make an array of the first four values in your sample.

Comment: @KenWhite,  using that algorithm you can get 80 and 5, and if exist any of other occurence you can get it too and store to some array as the answer suggest. But you never will get the 64 as I need.

Comment: Yes, you will. Two variables. Store the first two numbers, one in each. Take the next value; if it's higher than either of the two you have, replace that value with the new one. Do it again with the next number. When you're finished, you have the two highest values. The max is whichever is greatest. Done.

Comment: 24, 64, 3, 54. First two 24, 64. Store them. Next number 3 - less than both you have, so skip it. Next number 54 - higher than 24, so keep it instead. Now you end up with 64 and 54. Which one is greater? The first one, so it's max, and the other is second greatest. Simple to also store the indexes (your other two variables) at the same time you're storing the number. If it makes you feel better, you can add one more step - when you're ready to store a new value, compare the two you have, and if the second is greater than the first swap them. It adds complexity but keeps them in order always.

Comment: Really thank you @KenWhite , sorry i'm a little bit new in programming and these things are difficult to me, find people like you it's awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way we can do it using `reduce` and some generous destructuring assignment. Note `max2` returns `None` if the input has less than two (2) elements –

```js
const None =
  Symbol ('None')

const max2 = ([ a = None, b = None, ...rest ]) =>
  a === None || b === None
    ? None
    : rest .reduce
        ( ([ m1, m2 ], val, i) =>
            val > m1.val
              ? [ { val, i: i + 2 }, m1 ]
            : val > m2.val
              ? [ m1, { val, i: i + 2 } ]
            : [ m1, m2 ]
        , b < a
            ? [ { val: a, i: 0 }, { val: b, i: 1 } ]
            : [ { val: b, i: 1 }, { val: a, i: 0 } ]
        )

console .log
  ( max2 ([])
  // None

  , max2 ([ 1 ])
  // None

  , max2 ([ 24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20 ])
  // [ { val: 80, i: 5 }, { val: 64, i: 1 } ]

  , max2 ([ 1, 1000, 100, 101, 109, 99 ])
  // [ { val: 1000, i: 1 }, { val: 109: i 4 } ]

  , max2 ([ 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2 ])
  // [ { val: 9, i: 1 }, { val: 9, i: 0 } ]
  )
```

You asked what this would look like without using `reduce`. One way we can do this is by using a `helper` function and calling it recursively with updated arguments. We stop the recursive call when we arrive at a base case -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ('None')

const max2 = ([ a = None, b = None, ...rest ]) =>
  // if a or b are non-values ...
  a === None || b === None
    ? None   // return the empty result
  // when b is smaller than a
  : b < a
    ? helper                // call our helper
        ( { val: a, i: 0 }  // m1 is the larger value (a) with index 0
        , { val: b, i: 1 }  // m2 is the smaller value (b) with index 1
        , 2                 // start the next index at 2
        , rest              // the remaining values of the input list
        )
  // otherwise, b is larger than a
  : helper                 // call our helper
      ( { val: b, i: 1 }   // m1 is the larger value (b) at index 1
      , { val: a, i: 0 }   // m2 is the smaller value (a) at index 0
      , 2                  // start the next index at 2
      , rest               // the remaining values of the input list
      )

const helper = (m1, m2, i, [ val = None, ...rest ]) =>
  // base case
  val === None
    ? [ m1, m2 ]
  // val is greater than m1
  : val > m1.val
    ? helper         // recur ...
        ( { val, i } // replace m1 with new largest value (val)
        , m1         // replace m2 with previous largest value (m1)
        , i + 1      // increment index
        , rest       // with the rest of the list
        )
  // val is greater than m2
  : val > m2.val
    ? helper         // recur ...
        ( m1         // keep the previous largest value (m1)
        , { val, i } // replace m2 with new second largest value (val)
        , i + 1      // increment index
        , rest       // with the rest of the list
        )
  // otherwise
  : helper           // recur ...
      ( m1           // keep the largest value (m1)
      , m2           // keep the second largest value (m2)
      , i + 1        // increment index
      , rest         // with the rest of the list
      )

console .log
  ( max2 ([])
  // None

  , max2 ([ 1 ])
  // None

  , max2 ([ 24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20 ])
  // [ { val: 80, i: 5 }, { val: 64, i: 1 } ]

  , max2 ([ 1, 1000, 100, 101, 109, 99 ])
  // [ { val: 1000, i: 1 }, { val: 109: i 4 } ]

  , max2 ([ 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2 ])
  // [ { val: 9, i: 1 }, { val: 9, i: 0 } ]
  )
```

The technique can be generalized so that defining external functions like `helper` is not necessary. Instead, general functions `loop` and `recur` can be defined once and then called wherever you wish to utilize this technique. No hidden magic, just functions that accept arguments and guarantee a result -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc =
    f ()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const None =
  Symbol ('None')

const max2 = ([ a = None, b = None, ...values ]) =>
  a === None || b === None
    ? None
    : loop                             // loop with arguments ...
        ( ( m1 = { val: a, i: 0 }      // init m1 = ...
          , m2 = { val: b, i: 1 }      // init m2 = ...
          , i = 2                      // ...
          , [ val = None, ...rest ] = values
          ) =>
            // base case
            val === None
              ? [ m1, m2 ]  // <- no recur for base case
            // m1 must be larger than m2
            : m1.val < m2.val
              ? recur (m2, m1, i, [ val, ...rest ]) // <- retry with swapped m1 and m2
            // val > m1
            : val > m1.val
              ? recur ({ val, i }, m1, i + 1, rest) // <- recur
            // val > m2
            : val > m2.val
              ? recur (m1, { val, i }, i + 1, rest) // <- recur
            // otherwise
            : recur (m1, m2, i + 1, rest) // <- recur
        )

console .log
  ( max2 ([])
  // None

  , max2 ([ 1 ])
  // None

  , max2 ([ 24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20 ])
  // [ { val: 80, i: 5 }, { val: 64, i: 1 } ]

  , max2 ([ 1, 1000, 100, 101, 109, 99 ])
  // [ { val: 1000, i: 1 }, { val: 109: i 4 } ]

  , max2 ([ 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2 ])
  // [ { val: 9, i: 1 }, { val: 9, i: 0 } ]
  )
```

---

Above we find the two (2) max values, but we can expand our program to find the max *N* values -

```
console .log
  ( maxn (3, [])
  // None (less than 3 input values)

  , maxn (3, [ 1 ])
  // None (less than 3 input values)

  , maxn (3, [ 24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20 ])
  // [ { val: 80, i: 5 }, { val: 64, i: 1 }, { val: 54, i: 3 } ]

  , maxn (3, [ 1, 1000, 100, 101, 109, 99 ])
  // [ { val: 1000, i: 1 }, { val: 109, i: 4 }, { val: 101, i: 3 } ]

  , maxn (3, [ 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2 ])
  // [ { val: 9, i: 1 }, { val: 9, i: 2 }, { val: 9, i: 3 } ]
  )
```

Here's a possible implementation of `maxn` using `reduce` and a helper function `insert` -

```
const maxn = (n = 1, values = []) =>
  n >= values.length
    ? None
    : values .reduce
        ( (acc, val, i) =>
            insert ({ val, i }, acc)
        , []
        )
        .slice (0, n)

const insert = (a, [ b = None, ...rest ]) =>
  b == None
    ? [ a ]
  : a.val > b.val
    ? [ a, b, ...rest ]
  : [ b, ...insert (a, rest) ]
```

And again, but this time using our no-magic `loop` and `recur` -

```
const maxn = (n = 1, values = []) =>
  n >= values.length
    ? None
    : loop
        ( ( acc = []
          , i = 0
          ) =>
            i >= values.length
              ? n > acc.length
                ? None
                : acc .slice (0, n)
              : recur
                  ( insert
                      ({ val: values[i], i }
                      , acc
                      )
                  , i + 1
                  )
        )

const insert = (a, values = []) =>
  loop
    ( ( acc = []
      , [ b = None, ...rest ] = values
      ) =>
        b === None
          ? [ ...acc, a ]
        : a.val > b.val
          ? [ ...acc, b, ...rest ]
        : recur
            ( [ ...acc, b ]
            , rest
            )
    )
```

Expand the snippet below to read additional source comments and verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc =
    f ()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const None =
  Symbol ('None')

const maxn = (n = 1, [ val = None, ...values ]) =>
  val === None
    ? None
    : loop                    // init loop
        ( ( acc = []          // init accumulator as empty list
          , i = 0             // start at index 0
          ) =>
          // base case
          i >= values.length  // when i is out of bounds ...
            ? n > acc.length  // when accumulator has fewer than n values...
              ? None          // return None result
              : acc           // otherwise return the accumulator            
          // inductive
          : recur
              ( insert        // insert new value into accumlator
                  ({ val: values[i], i: i + 1 }
                  , acc
                  )
                  .slice (0, n) // only keep at most n values
              , i + 1         // increment index
              )
        )

const insert = (a, [ b = None, ...rest ]) =>
  // base case
  b == None
    ? [ a ]
  // a is larger than b
  : a.val > b.val
    ? [ a, b, ...rest ]
  // otherwise
  : [ b, ...insert (a, rest) ]

console .log
  ( maxn (3, [])
  // None (less than 3 input values)

  , maxn (3, [ 1 ])
  // None (less than 3 input values)

  , maxn (3, [ 24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20 ])
  // [ { val: 80, i: 5 }, { val: 64, i: 1 }, { val: 54, i: 3 } ]

  , maxn (3, [ 1, 1000, 100, 101, 109, 99 ])
  // [ { val: 1000, i: 1 }, { val: 109, i: 4 }, { val: 101, i: 3 } ]

  , maxn (3, [ 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2 ])
  // [ { val: 9, i: 1 }, { val: 9, i: 2 }, { val: 9, i: 3 } ]
  )
```

Comment: Uoo, reallyl thank you, do you know any way to do that without reduce function? i'm really new in js and i don't understand the code correctly

Comment: Same comment as for idelara's answer.

Comment: Using `[115, 24, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20, 100, 120, 20, 120, 110]` like you said gives `120` and `120` as they are the largest two numbers in this array... What do you think the answer should be?

Comment: @Raikish I updated my answer. Let me know if you still have questions :D

Comment: You need to change the number, not insert them, so: [115, 64, 3, 54, 2, 80, 20, 100, 120, 20, 110].  Some of the edge cases with just 2 or 3 element arrays also look a little off.

Comment: @user633183 Looks awesome dude, really thank you for your explanation

Comment: @Ben, I now see what you were trying to say. I the program broke with certain inputs, but now it is fixed. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Raikish I added a generic solution for finding the max _N_ elements; no longer limited to two :D

Comment: @user633183 Awesome!